# VBA: Format all font in document

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

This code worked when used in MS Word, now trying to run from excel. I want to format all the text in the document with the same font type and the same font size.

```
'Format document with universal font type and size
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    Selection.Font.Size = 11
    End With
```

This one also did not work:

```
ActiveDocument.Range.Font.Color = wdColorAutomatic
ActiveDocument.Range.Font.Name = "Calibri"
ActiveDocument.Range.Font.Size = 11
```

Comment: All the text in a word document, or an excel spreadsheet?

Comment: word document, code is being run from excel, this is inserted after asked about what word document to open

Comment: I think it will be an issue with your `Selection`. You should use a more direct way.

Comment: would something like Active document work?

Comment: `Selection.WholeStory` is specific to Microsoft Word: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.wholestory(v=office.11).ASPX

Comment: You should use the Document object I think.. [This link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/581801-visual-basic-applications-format-text-word.html) may help you.

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is in continuation to your last question. Try this. I have not deleted certain declarations from the previous code.

```
Const wdFindContinue = 1

Sub FnFindAndFormat()
    Dim FileToOpen
    Dim objWord As Object, objDoc As Object, Rng As Object
    Dim MyAr() As String, strToFind As String
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> This holds your search words
    strToFind = "deal,contract,sign,award"

    '~~> Create an array of text to be found
    MyAr = Split(strToFind, ",")

    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (Title:="Please choose a file to import", _
    FileFilter:="Word Files *.docx (*.docx),")

    If FileToOpen = False Then Exit Sub

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    '~~> Open the relevant word document
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(FileToOpen)

    objWord.Visible = True

    Set Rng = objDoc.Content

    With Rng
        .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Font.Size = 11
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice.. So I guess the `Content` is what he needed?

Answer (score 0):

Set constant at top:

Const wdColorAutomatic = -16777216

```
objDoc.Range.Font.Color = wdColorAutomatic
        objDoc.Range.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        objDoc.Range.Font.Size = 11
```

Comment: `wdColorAutomatic` will not work if you have not declared it at the top :) Remember you are latebinding ;) You need to declare `Const wdColorAutomatic = -16777216` at the top