# Change font size for whole document

Tags: c#, docx, novacode-docx

I am trying to make a document but my font is currently to big.

Currenty i am changing the font like this

```
t2.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("Data").FontSize(9);
```

Is there a way to change the font size for the whole document ?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965004/vba-format-all-font-in-document) shows how to do it using VBA

Comment: 'doc.AddCoreProperty("FontSize", "70");' i thought i try it like this but it does not work